# Radio Buttons Customer Style

Tags: html, css

I want to style radio buttons, only one is selected at a time, but somehow it doesn't work.

The customer style is showing, but checked style somehow doesn't work. Is something missing?

Please help.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whpqto54/1/)

Below is my HTML

```
<div class="radio-button pull-right">
  <span>
    Yes
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="Yes" value="Yes" class="mr10">
    <div class="radio-style"></div>
  </span>
  <span>
    No
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="No" value="No" class="mr10">
    <div class="radio-style"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Below is my CSS

```
body {
  background: black
}

.radio-button {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white
}
input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
 input:checked .radio-style:before {
    display: block;
 }

.radio-style {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-style:before {
  content: "";
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replaced yours spans with label and I've changed `input:checked .radio-style:before` with `input:checked+.radio-style:before`. This is selecting the `.radio-style:before`  that comes immediately after a checked input.

```css
body {
  background: black
}

.radio-button {
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white
}
input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0
}
 input:checked+.radio-style:before {
    display: block;
 }

.radio-style {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-style:before {
  content: "";
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-button pull-right">
  <label> 
    Yes
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="Yes" value="Yes" class="mr10">
    <div class="radio-style"></div>
  </label>
  <label>
    No
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="No" value="No" class="mr10">
    <div class="radio-style"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```